# Selenium IDE gives SyntaxError: JSON.parse: bad control character in string literal

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome, selenium

I installed Selenium IDE 2.9.1.
After starting Selenium IDE and pressing File/Resent test cases I receive an error message:

> There was an unexpected error. Msg: TypeError: this.app is undefined
>   Url: chrome://selenium-ide/content/editor.js, line: 1013, column: 7
>   Editor.prototype.populateFormatsPopup@chrome://selenium-ide/content/editor.js:1013:7
>   onpopupshowing@chrome://selenium-ide/content/selenium-ide-sidebar.xul:1:1

Also when I open Selenium IDE I receive an error message:

> There was an unexpected error. Msg: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: bad control  character in string literal at line 1 column 1905 of the JSON data
>   Url: chrome://selenium-ide/content/plugin.js, line: 17, column: 22
>   PluginManager.prototype.load@chrome://selenium-ide/content/plugin.js:17:22
>   PluginManager@chrome://selenium-ide/content/plugin.js:7:3
>   Application@chrome://selenium-ide/content/application.js:26:26
>   Editor@chrome://selenium-ide/content/editor.js:30:14
>   SidebarEditor@chrome://selenium-ide/content/sidebar-editor.js:22:5
>   onload@chrome://selenium-ide/content/selenium-ide-sidebar.xul:1:1

System:

- Firefox: 43 Language Hungarian
- Selenium IDE 2.9.1
- Windows 10*

I already removed and reinstalled selenium plugin from here:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/selenium-ide/

Also I removed other FF plugins.

Any idea how to solve this problem? As actually I can not use Selenium in FF...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like an issue with Selenium IDE: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=8103

Suggested solution is as follows:

1. Type "about:config" in the address bar of Mozilla Firefox.
2. Change the settings to "default" for extensions.javaformatters@seleniumhq.org.install-event-fired and
   extensions.selenium-ide.pluginsData.
3. Close and Now launch the IDE again.

Comment: Thank you @parishodak , it works based on your suggestion!

Comment: [Naresh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/288917/naresh-kanduru) I can't see  extensions.javaformatters@seleniumhq.org.install-event-fired  in my about:config in Firefox..How do I add these extensions to Firefox?

Comment: @Vikash.777 have you installed selenium IDE on firefox?

Comment: Yes [Naresh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/288917/naresh-kanduru), I have installed a latest version of Firefox with selenium IDE.

Comment: @Vikash.777, I doubt you have incompatible Firefox and IDE. Which versions for Firefox and IDE you have installed?

Comment: Yeah,[parishodak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/288917/parishodak), you are right.It shows that you have incompatible Firefox and IDE. So how to get right compatible connfiguration? And what are they? Do you know?

Comment: refer https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/selenium-expert-selenium-ide/versions/

Comment: Hi there. I use Firefox 43 (en-US version) with Selenium IDE 2.9.1 and install Selenium Expert 'Version 0.25.1-signed.1-signed'. There is still no such setting in about:config. After I record a test case, I click on Source pane. There is an unexpected error. Msg: TypeError: text.replace is not a function

Comment: @user3454439 pls add more details to the issue you are facing, preferably on a new question. you will get a faster response.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are experiencing this because of a conflict with a JavaScript framework, such as mootools.

In my case,

1. executeScript on document.title = 'Hello World';

   - initally works
2. I load a web page using an old copy of mootools
3. executeScript on document.title = 'Hello World';

   - no longer works with the error message "Failed: HH:MM:SS JSON.parse is not a function"